# Contentful regex to check if all characters are lowercase

Tags: regex, contentful

I know there a 1,000,000 regex questions but I have one I've been unable to find the answer too

In contentful (a headless CMS software) you can set validations for certain fields

[image]

Now I have set this regex `[a-z]+` to check if the string provided in this field is all lowercase letters (numbers and symbols are ok), but when I test it out, I am still allowed to use Capital letters.

Is my regex wrong? Or am I entering it wrong in this field??

Comment: Try this maybe? `^[^A-Z]*$`

Comment: Contentful apparently uses [Javascript's](https://www.contentful.com/r/knowledgebase/validations/#regex) regex syntax..

Comment: @AlphaDelta yes thankyou! this worked

Comment: @SmokeyDawson That allows _any_ character except uppercase alphabets though (and even empty strings due to the *). If you don't want eg. numbers, just surround your own expression with ^ and $

Comment: @Ivar yes that is what I want numbers and symbols are ok, just no uppercase letters

Comment: @Ivar ive updated question